# Is there a non-verbose way to notate finger sustained notes in LilyPond?

Tags: chords, sheet-music, lilypond, sustain

I recently started learning LilyPond and am trying to notate finger sustained notes as described in [Is there piano notation for finger sustained notes (as opposed to pedal sustain)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/is-there-piano-notation-for-finger-sustained-notes-as-opposed-to-pedal-sustain). I would be fine with either one of the notations from the top two answers.

I was able to notate what's described in the second answer like so:

```
\relative f' { f4~ <f c'>~ <f c' f>2 }
```

[image]

I find the code I wrote very verbose because I have to repeat all of the previous notes whenever I add a new one. Ideally I would only need to specify the next note and that I'd like the previous notes to continue and tie over. Is there a less verbose way to express this or what's described in the top answer of the question I linked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether it's possible to shorten the code you have provided (I doubt it but perhaps someone will know a way). However you could use `\set tieWaitForNote = ##t` to a good effect here. When it is set to `##t`, each note with tie waits for the next occurrence of the same note and ties it with that. So your snippet could be rewritten like this:

```
\relative f' { \set tieWaitForNote = ##t f4~ c'~ <f c' f>2 }
```

which would result in the first `f` tying right to the half-note `f`, without the need for the second `f` in between.

You can play with it in a [lilybin](http://lilybin.com/uqd31t/1) that I put together for that.